# failed to connect to FTP server from batch script

Tags: batch-file, ftp, backup

I can connect successfully to my ftp server from cmd but when i execute the .bat script to connect to ftp server it gives me:

```
503 Login authentication failed identification failure.
```

I'm sure my password and username are correct so could be any other reason that gives that error?
My .bat script is:

```
ftp -s:ftp.txt
```

And my ftp.txt file is:

```
open ftpserver
username  
password
cd C:\backups
lcd C:\backups
put C:\backups\bk.backup 
bye
```

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your username or password may have spaces after it.

The problem from your script is the authentication - that's the first three lines of the txt file.

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't notice that there was a space after username until you said it. Thank you:)

Comment: Please open a new question - as StackOverflow is designed to answer one question at a time.